# Oracle: sum values in quantity column “not a single-group group function error”

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables called **PRODUCT** and **LINEITEMS** and I am trying to use a combination of a JOIN and GROUP BY to display a single row for each product with the total quantity sold next to it. The structure of the tables is as follows:

- PRODUCT (partno#, description, category, unitcost, unitprice)
- LINEITEM (order#, line#, partno#, quantity, unitprice

I've got this far but the quantity displayed next to each product is the sum of all quantities from all products and not the sum of the quantity sold for that product on the line.

```
SELECT p.description, sum(li.quantity)
FROM product p, linetem li
GROUP BY p.description;
```

Comment: Yes, the one you are using is a cross join. If you don't want that it is better if you use inner join or other join explicitly on any columns from these two tables

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

*Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Your query is missing `JOIN` conditions.  Something like this:

```
SELECT p.description, sum(li.quantity)
FROM product p JOIN
     linetem li
     ON p.partno# = li.partno#
GROUP BY p.description;
```